# Building single fat jar from a multi module maven project - including test classes

Tags: maven, selenium, testing

I'm in a situation where I need to build a fat jar from a multi module maven project. The project is built based on Selenium/cucumber API's.

Structure of my project is as follows

```
   Parent -- pom
   |
   |__core_module src/main/java --> helper classes for selenium
   |
   |__acme_module src/main/test --> Test Classes for acme project
```

I have tried different ways to build a "acme_test.jar" which includes core_module+acme_module.But none of them helped me.

Much appreciate any clue to solve this .

Thanks

Comment: It is really unclear what you want to do here. What is `acme_test.jar`, what are `acme_module` and the rest, what do they contain exactly, how do they relate...?

Comment: It is all about to build a helper framework for selenium test cases say, for acme. The core_module will hold the all helper and utility classes for selenium and the acme_module will hold the test classes for "acme". What we are trying is to build a fat jar (executable – core_module+acme_module = acme_fat_test.jar) from these two modules (with all dependencies) to a not that tech savvy client to avoid related set up.

Comment: Do you mean `src/test/java`? Is this `src/main/test` correct?

Comment: @kallada : I'm sorry but your explanation did not make it clearer. Is your objective to have in the end an executable jar so that the tests will be run when you're going to execute it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @MariuszS mentions, first restructure your project so that you separate any Unit tests or integration tests for the actual classes that test (=drive/verify navigation for) Acme.

```
   Parent -- pom
   |
   |__core_module src/main/java --> helper classes for selenium
   |
   |__acme_module src/main/java --> Classes specific for navigating acme 
   |
   |__acme_module src/test/java--> (Unit etc) Test Classes for acme project
```

Then, you need acme_module to contain core_module as dependency.

Finally, in acme_module, put this in your build plugins section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-fat-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                    <finalName>YourJarName</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can also explicitly include the core_module by adding an include filter in the plugin configuration section

Comment: And of course the core module should also have its tests under _core_module/src/test/java_.

Comment: Alternatively, if you do not want your modules unpacked inside the shaded jar, you can use [onejar-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/onejar-maven-plugin/) so as to create an uber JAR of nested JARs, i.e. there is a special classloader loading the unchanged JARs directly from the uber JAR. Also available on Maven Central via [this fork](https://github.com/jolira/onejar-maven-plugin). If you (kallada) want to know more about it and I have a chance of you accepting it as an answer, just tell me and I will prepare one. But Maven Shade will also do the job, this answer is correct.

Comment: Sorry, guys couldn't respond to you people in time due to some personal reasons.

Answer (score 4):

Configure `acme_module` as fat module - this module should produce executable fat jar with all dependencies.

Add `core_module` to `acme_module` as dependency.

Move your test classes from `src/test/java` to `src/main/java`, because this class should be executable. If you have tests (like junit), then leave this classes inside `test` directory, but executable part should stay in `main`.